# Where can I download Age of Mythology: Rise of the Titans? 

Tags: age-of-mythology

Despite Age of Mythology being rather old it's still one of my favorite games. Unfortunately my disk for the Rise of the Titans expansion pack has gotten scratched over the years and now no longer works. Is there anywhere I can download it? I still have the activation key and disk and am willing to pay to be able to play it again. Every download link I have found, legal or otherwise, has not worked. Please help me play this classic game again.

Comment: amazon? ebay? I can find a few for sale just by browsing these sites.

Comment: Heh, was interested a few days ago, and I think best bet is amazon. If you're able to find it at a store, it's likely that the CD key has already been used (happened to me a year or so ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A microsoft employee told me to do a flat installation and the part of the game that didn't copy over doesn't seem to be vital, so the game still works. Here's a link to the conversation http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/age-of-mythology-rise-of-the-titans-download/75c846f7-d961-4827-9025-59b7965e4141?tm=1349555170992

Answer (score 4):

As stated at the [Microsoft support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258496), you can do this to get another disc:

> Obtain a replacement disc
>
> To obtain a replacement disc from Microsoft in the United States, contact the Microsoft Order Desk at (800) 360-7561. If you are outside the United States, visit the following website to learn how to obtain a replacement disc:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support
>
> For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>   [326246](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246) How to replace Microsoft software or hardware, order service packs and product upgrades, or replace product manuals.